# Is there a downside to creating numerous app pools?

Tags: web-application, app

I am creating new web applications and creating a new app pool each time. Is there a downside to doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Application Pools are [fairly expensive](http://thesharepointfarm.com/2014/08/expense-application-pools/). I will often advocate/build farms with the minimum number of accounts possible (for those covering App Pools, that would be a Farm Admin, Service App, and Web App account).

With .NET, there is minimal memory sharing between processes, and the SharePoint binaries consume quite a bit of memory without any end user activity.

Comment: OK - I'm creating the app pools on the Development server though. So will this still be an issue?

Comment: That would be your decision to make. There's nothing stating that it is wrong/will cause an issue, but just know that there is an increased memory usage. If you have 32GB RAM dev server and you create 5 Web App Pools but you're the only user, no you're not going to run into memory issues (most likely).

Answer (score 2):

The downside is: you can hit the recommended limit of 10 app pools: see https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262787.aspx#WebserverAppServer.
Also note the limit of Web applications (20).

Comment: Is there any reasons to why there is a recommended limit? Please elaborate your answer.

Comment: Unfortunately, the article I mentioned is the best resource we can have on this subject. As they suggest, it's all a matter of performances (remember accounts, check health, monitor services...). Plus, to be honest, a matter of maintenance. Also, dont forget that you also have the 20 Web apps limit...